# Vim Only Highlighting ~/.vimrc

Tags: vim, syntax, colors, highlight, highlighting

I am a new vim user and trying to turn on syntax coloring for vim on Mac OS X. I followed http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Turn_on_syntax_coloring_in_Mac_OS_X's instructions, and my ~/.vimrc file has the following content

```
set term=builtin_ansi
filetype plugin indent on
syntax on
```

And the text above in ~/.vimrc is highlighted perfectly fine. However, whenever I use vim to edit a current text file or create a new one, I only see black and white text, and manually calling :syntax on does nothing. Any help is apprecaited!

Comment: Text files don't have any particular highlighting defined for them. You might want to try other filetypes, like ruby, javascript, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `:highlight` command to list all defined groups (according to your *colorscheme*). A plain text file probably has no *filetype* and therefore no syntax assigned; you want to try this with any programming language (e.g. `*.py` or `*.c`) to see syntax highlighting in action.

Your `~/.vimrc` looks fine. (Do you really need the `:set term`, though?!)

Answer (score 1):

You should remove that useless line:

```
set term=builtin_ansi
```

Do you use the default Vim? What filetypes are you editing?